# React - Ajax data not being passed into Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, one parent one child.  I am using the fetch method in `componentDidMount()` callback.  Once I do this, I set the state with key items to that data that is pulled from the api.  Once I do this it should be able to be console logged in the child component as a prop.  However this is not working.  What am I doing wrong here?

Parent Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Map from './maps/Map';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "John",
            items: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=')
        .then(dat => dat.json())
        .then(dat => {
            this.setState({
                items: dat.hits
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Map list={this.state.name} items={this.state.items}></Map>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Child Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Map extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props.items)
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: do ```render () {
console.log(this.props.items)
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        )
    }```

Comment: It does here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aywmmj

Comment: Yes you are right.  Why does it catch console.log in the render and not in the constructor?  Shouldnt it do in both? This is a fundamental I cannot wrap aroudn my head

Comment: look at the example I posted above

Comment: Your parameter is called `list=` so `name` is undefined in the `Map` component. As for the constructor, it does run when you first create the component, but when it re-renders to receive more props, the constructor isn't called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) for a component only runs one time during a lifecycle. When it does, `props.items` is undefined because your ajax request is in-flight, so `console.log(props.items)` doesn't show anything.

If you change your constructor to `console.log("constructed");`, you'll see one-time output (stack snippets may not show this--look in your browser console). Henceforth, [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) can be used to see the new props that were set when your ajax request finishes.

You could also log the props inside the `render` method, which will run once before the ajax request resolves and again afterwards when `props.items` changes.

As a side point, you have `<Map list=...` but the component tries to render `this.props.name`, which is undefined.

Also, if you aren't doing anything in the constructor (initializing state or binding functions) as here, you don't need it.

```js
class Map_ /* _ added to avoid name clash */ extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("constructed");
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const props = JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2);
    console.log("I got new props", props);
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
        <pre>
          <ul>
            {this.props.items.map((e, i) => 
              <li key={i}>{JSON.stringify(e, null, 2)}</li>)}
          </ul>
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: "John", items: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=')
      .then(dat => dat.json())
      .then(dat => {
        this.setState({items: dat.hits})
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map_
          name={this.state.name} 
          items={this.state.items}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Main />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I wanted to know.  That the constructor of the Child doesnt catch the change of the ajax fetch from parent as it is probably only called once. Can I set the state of the Child component to the props in componentDidUpdate() ?

Comment: Yes, but you need a condition to prevent infinite re-renders. See the docs for [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). Also, copying props into state directly is an antipattern, also described in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

First, `fetch` is asynchronous. So, the fetch statement might be pending by the time you try to console.log the result inside the child constructor.

Putting the console.log inside the `render` method would work, because the component will be rerendered, if the state `items` changes.

Comment: so what you are saying is that only the render method can catch an async change int the props?  Can i not catch the async change elsewhere in the Child component???

Comment: No, thats not what I am saying. An async call is not handled like sequential statements. In your case putting the `console.log` inside `render` works, because the whole component will be rerendered, if a state changes. The constructor is just called once, when the object is constructed / instantiated.

Comment: So what do  i have to do to be able to make the prop change in the constructor?  As of now it doesnt console log anything in the constructor after the async call.

Comment: If you want to be able to use the async property inside the child constructor, then you have to be sure, that the child is instantiated, when the fetch is done. You can use `Portals` of React for that.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you have is that you are trying to use `this.props.name` and your `Map` component props are called `list` and `items`, so it will return `undefined`.

If you log your props in the constructor you will get the initial state of `Main` because the fetch hasn't returned anything yet. Remember that the constructor only runs once. So you are probably getting an empty array when you log `props.items` in the constructor because that's what you have in your initial state.

```
{
  name: "John",
  items: []
}
```

If you log the props in your render method you will see your array filled with the data you fetched, as you can see here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-cache-m7d43

If you don't want to show the component until the data is fetched you can include a boolean property in your state that you set to true once you the fetch returns a response and pass it as a prop to your component. Your component can you use that variable to show, for example, a spinner while you are fetching the data. Here's an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-edison-in9w4

```
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress"

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "John",
      items: [],
      fecthed: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=")
      .then(dat => dat.json())
      .then(dat => {
        this.setState({
          items: dat.hits,
          fecthed: true
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        fetched={this.state.fecthed}
        list={this.state.name}
        items={this.state.items}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Map extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.fetched ? (
          <div>
            <h1>{this.props.list}</h1>
            {this.props.items.map((item, indx) => (
              <div key={indx}>Author: {item.author}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <CircularProgress />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.  It did help yes.